# Make [desktop-recording] a synonym of [screencast]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[screencast](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/screencast) and [desktop-recording](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/desktop-recording) almost mean the same thing.

I say almost, because there may be some subtle differences. But I don't believe they are enough to keep the tags separated.
For example, a [screencast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screencast) *may* contain audio narration. But I think desktop recording may have that as well.
Also, one can argue that a screencast should be a recording of the whole screen, while desktop recording doesn't need to be. But I can't find any definition of either word which says that.

Currently, screencast has 101 questions, while desktop-recording has 54.

Maybe [screencast](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/screencast) should be a synonym of [desktop-recording](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/desktop-recording) but honestly, I'm not sure how the synonyms feature really works.

Comment: Seems reasonable as long as desktop recording is okay with fielding livestreaming questions.

Comment: Screencasting is a subset of desktop recording, so if anything, these should be merged into desktop-recording.

Comment: @TheWanderer why do you think that screencasting is a subset of desktop recording?

Comment: Am with you, the difference is so subtle it does not help in making them different. Go here to add or support the one created right now https://askubuntu.com/tags/screencast/synonyms but makes total sense Dan.

Comment: @muru because screencasting involves recording your desktop (ie screen), just not necessarily saving that recording.

Comment: @TheWanderer then isn't screencasting more general than desktop-recording, and thus a superset?

Comment: @LuisAlvarado unfortunately I don't currently have enough score on that tag to be able to vote on the synonym.

Answer (score 5):

For me, both are synonyms to be specific and not go around the bush. Anything mentioned about one will still land on the other one. What can both do:

- Record small videos
- Record long videos
- Record parts of the desktop
- Record specific windows on the desktop
- Record video only
- Record video and audio
- Stream recording to 3rd party source
- Live stream
- Save in popular different formats
- Compress raw recording
- Some option that wants to be applied to one but not the other and then realize, wait a minute batman, this applies to the other one too
- Realizing thanks to batman that both are the same thing.

Comment: So, can we have them synonymized in one direction or the other?

Comment: Yeah. I see no problem there. I would actually just use the idea of which one was used more often as base to know which one would be the base.